# Заполнение таблицы разными медианами

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Даны две таблицы. Одна — это датафрейм, вторая с **медианами зарплат** в зависимости от **занятости**.

```
      **занятость**   **медиана зарплат**

    0   безработный     131339.751676
    1   в декрете       53829.130729
    2   госслужащий     150447.935283
    3   компаньон       172357.950966
    4   пенсионер       118514.486412
    5   предприниматель 499163.144947
    6   сотрудник       142594.396847
    7   студент         98201.625314
```

Как заполнить пропуски в датафрейме разными медианами? То есть если есть пропуск в зарплате пенсионера в датафрейме, то нужно, чтобы он заполнился именно медианой которая ему соответствует.

Исходные данные имеют вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я придумал условие, которое можно вручную сделать по каждому пункту, но как сохранить изменения пока не придумал. То есть после всех условий исходный **df** не меняется, и все равно есть пропуски.

```
    df[df['income_type'] == 'сотрудник'] ['total_income'].fillna(142594.396847)
```

Comment: Примеры исходных данных приведите.

Comment: Добавил скриншот.

Comment: Воспроизводимый пример нужен. зачем нам ваш скриншот, ей-богу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто там про воспроизводимый пример пишет, я не знаю что это такое.
**Первый вариант.**
Набросали мне такой код в цикле можно сделать!

```
for income_item in df['income_type'].unique():
for education_item in df['education'].unique():

    median_value = df[(df['income_type'] == income_item) & (df['education'] == education_item)]['total_income'].median()

    df.loc[(df['income_type'] == income_item) & (df['education'] == education_item), 'total_income'] = df.loc[(df['income_type'] == income_item) & (df['education'] == education_item), 'total_income'].fillna(median_value)
```

**Второй вариант** через групировку по условию/условиям и  фунуцию transform()

```
median_table = df.groupby('income_type')['total_income'].transform('median')
```

А позже передать эту таблицу для заполнения пропусков.

```
df['total_income'] = df['total_income'].fillna(median_table)
```

Comment: Насчет воспроизводимого примера: настоятельно рекомендую почитать [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Нужно просто продумать по шагам действия

- делаем фильтр интересующих нас записей с `NA` в доходе
- заполняем их, соединяя с датафреймом с медианным доходом

```
df_mask = df['total_income'].isna()
df.loc[df_mask, 'total_income'] = \
    df.loc[df_mask, ['сотрудник']].join(df_median, on='сотрудник')['median_income']
```

Код приблизительный, но должно работать. Вы в своём коде никуда результат не присваиваете, поэтому он не запоминается.

Comment: "результат не присваиваете, поэтому он не запоминается." я это понимаю) Спасибо!

Comment: Может, вы еще поймете, что без воспроизводимого примера данных никто вам конкретного ответа не даст?